# Multiple Many-To-Many relationships scenario in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-schema

I'm a beginner in SQL and Database management, I have an idea that I don't know how to model into database tables.

I have these tables : `users`, `orders`, `bills`, `lessons`, `tickets`, `coaches`.

- Lessons are posted by coaches.
- The users are able to order lessons.
- A bill is registered after the order.
- The users are also able to order tickets.
- A ticket gives access to a lesson.
- When users buy a ticket, the coache benefit or half or the ticket price.

So when a user buy a ticket that costs 6$ for a specific lesson, the coache who owns the lesson will get 3$.

Do I need another `bills` table for the `coaches`? or I can use the same `bills` table to register their gains from the purchased lessons?
I really have no idea how to achive my List of ideas above, sorry.

For now I've just managed to do this, I don't know how to complete the rest of the DB.

```
|bills|<--|orders| *<------ |users|
            |
            v
            *
        |order_lesson|
            *
            /\
            |
        |lessons| *<----- |coaches|
```

I can't ask you for a complete answer, but I really need some explication or guidance.

Comment: It looks like the amount given to coaches is at a fixed rate. If this is the instance from what I can tell there is no need for another table as you can easily calculate the amount the coach will get through a query. If you need more info or a more detailed report of each lesson then a bills category might be best.

Comment: The most important thing to remember in SQL is that there should be as little repetition of data in each table. As in if a table has a ton of repetition then you might need to look into refactoring your database

Comment: @Matthew I see, thank you.

Comment: I'd be grateful If you have an idea of how I can complete the DB by implementing the list of points that I mentioned at the beginning. And if is my current database is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell the ticket is no different then a regular order and can be placed with the orders as the only difference is the money the coach gets. So maybe just a column in the `orders` table would signify the type of order.

```
 |bills|<--|orders|<----|users|
                / \
                 |
              |lessons|<---|coaches|
```